# Aligning a String in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a string that I want to display in a `JOptionPane`.

```
String info = "Name:" + _name + "\n" +
              "Phone:" + _phone;
```

I tried to add `\t` but it didn't work.

I tried also to

```
int choose = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,new JTextArea(info),"XXX",0);
```

But it doesn't look good.

Are there another ways to do that? (*If you know about a solution where I can use something like `\t` it will be very usefull for me*)

***** *In this specific example I can manually align it, but I'm looking for a general solution*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTML` formatting could help:

```
String info = "Name:" + _name + "<br>" +
              "Phone:" + _phone + "<br>";

int choose = 
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "<html>" + info + "</html>", "XXX", 0);
```

Another option is to use a `JTable` in the `JOptionPane` dialog as shown in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702689/joptionpane-displaying-html-problems-in-java?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Comment: I tried to do so, still doesn't work. (I have more fields, not only `_name` and `_phone`. I want to align it so `_name`, `_phone` and another fields will start from the same column).

Comment: You could use a `HTML` table or use `CSS` to do alignment

Answer (score 1):

I had something like that and it worked:

```
String st =        "<table border = \"0\">" +
                   "<tr><td>VALUE1:  </td><td>" + _value2 + "</td></tr>"+
                   "<tr><td>VALUE2:  </td><td>" + _value4 + "</td></tr>" +
                   //.....
                   "</table>";
```